# npm 7 installed but version 6 is still wanted

Tags: npm

I recently updated npm to the latest version (7.1.1) using the following command:

```
npm i -g npm@7.1.1
```

It successfully installed npm 7.1.1, but when I check for global outdated packages I get this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JzCS.png

How can I set the wanted version of npm to >7.0 so that I don't get this anymore in the outdated list?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs for `npm outdated`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-outdated) indicate that when running `npm outdated --global`, the `Wanted` column "shows the currently-installed version." Since it is not doing that, that would seem to be a bug in `npm`. Either the `Wanted` column should display 7.1.1 in your case or else the documentation needs to be updated to reflect the actual behavior. (I've confirmed the same behavior on my own machine, so I don't believe this is a case of user error.) I suggest opening an issue in [the `npm` issue tracker](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues).

Comment: Thanks. I followed your suggestion and opened a bug in the npm issue tracker. When I get feedback I'll update this ticket.